# Show source of vue component in-app

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I would like to have a page with some vue component (say, a TODO-list) and a View-Source/live-demo toggle that the user can activate to switch between the working component and its source code.

Now, Is there any way I can grab the raw code of a .vue file inside my application?

Like:

```
import Todo from './components/Todo.vue'
//use Todo as a component, no problema
var todocode = getRawCode('./components/Todo.vue'); //how do I do this?
```

I'm using webpack as my bundler and one idea I have is that maybe I could `require('./components/Todo.vue', someNinjaOptionsHereMaybe)` somehow overriding the `vue-loader` (configured by default in my `webpack.config.js` for `.vue` files) with `file-loader` "just this once" in the application - but I don't have a clue if that is actually possible.

Thoughts?

---

UPDATE

As per @Saurabh request, I'll try to explain how exactly I'd like to use this.

[This](https://tonylampada.github.io/boravue/webpack-simple/docs.html) is what I call a "component catalog" (Click on "Dashboard" to expand and see two available components: IssuesDocs and TodoDocs)

Notice that the [docs application](https://github.com/tonylampada/boravue/tree/gh-pages/webpack-simple/docs) found those two components dynamically - if I create any file that matches src/**/*Docs.vue, it will be added to the component list in the left, and it will be available in the right when the user clicks on it.

In the view in the right I'd like to have a tab view with two options: "View" and "Code".

"View" will show the working component (like it does right now), and "Code" will show the code, for it, for example, in the case of "TodoDocs", code will show the contents of TodoDocs.vue file, like so:

```
<template>
  <Todo>
</template>

<script>

import Todo from '../Todo.vue'

export default {
  name: 'TodoDocs',
  components: {Todo}
}
</script>
```

This serves as "executable documentation" of how to use the Todo component (which, in this case is as easy as importing and adding a `<Todo>` tag).

I have found that having a component catalog like this is quite helpful when you're in a medium-to-big sized team working on the same application. I have succeeded implementing this concept using AngularJs, now I'm trying to do the same thing with vuejs.

Comment: interesting, Can you elaborate what you want to achieve by getting the raw code?

Comment: the browser does it through source map files, may be there is the solution.

Comment: @TonyLâmpada are you looking for a way to get unbundled, unprocessed code of a Vue file while the application is running i.e. the source code?

Comment: I need the unbundled, unprocessed code to be _available_ at runtime, but ideally the proper time to get it is at build time, I think

Comment: I just read a while ago on webpack's docs [1] that I can require("my-loader!./my-awesome-module");
And I found raw-loader [2] that can require files into strings.
I'm still not able to put things together though (I got stuck when I required('raw-loader!.....TodoDocs.vue') and got a string with "compiled" js code instead of vue code)
I opened an issue (=question) on raw-loader repo to see if maybe they can help :P
[1] https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html
[2] https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader/issues

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In an unbelievable turn of events, I actually found a solution for this.

It turns out i can `require(!!my-loader!my-module)` and I found this [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) that does what I want.

So making [this change](https://github.com/tonylampada/boravue/commit/62d2ec371d6bb5a152edfa662053217c581b7140#diff-a4c0d543ca6419b2418811d76ce76b6fR4) to my code actually allowed me to load the .vue components **and then** load it again with raw-loader to get its source.

It works, unbelievable.

The working result is [live](https://tonylampada.github.io/boravue/webpack-simple/docs.html#/view/TodoDocs)